# Is there a way to limit bandwidth usage on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

Often, I tether my Android smartphone to my Windows 7 PC, while travelling. This office PC has many background data-consuming applications (like software update, virus definition downloads, large bulky email downloads, and other synchronization software) that rapidly consumes data, from the rather expensive roaming data-plan.

Wondering, if there is some software or configuration available on Windows 7, to limit how much bandwidth is available to the PC, via phone ?

AFAIK, many Windows applications detect that they are on low-bandwidth connectivity and resort to reduced usage of data network.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-bandwidth-manager-android-t2972889  If you can find this application or something similar it could really help you out.

Comment: Thanks @NetworkKingPin, that's a good alternative indeed.

Comment: I have used NetBalacncer to do this...http://www.technorms.com/1495/easily-set-bandwidth-limit-on-a-per-program-basis-with-netbalancer

Comment: @Moab that should be good enough as an answer.

Comment: @icarus74 Software recommendations are not answers here on SU. That is why it is a comment.

Comment: Ah indeed, understood.